# Prevent the launch screen from fading to black on Flutter / Android

Tags: android, flutter, splash-screen, launch-screen

I added a launch screen consisting of a PNG image to my Flutter app (Android). There is a very noticeable "fade to black" between the launch screen and the Flutter app being displayed. I'm not talking about a sudden black screen, but the launch screen really fades out for ~500 ms and then the Flutter app appears.

I have followed the [migration guide](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects) to use Android Embedding v2 (but I wasn't using a splash screen before, so I don't know if the migration is the cause of this issue).

This is my `launch_background.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:drawable="@drawable/wood1" />

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_foreground" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and this is my `normal_background.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:drawable="@drawable/wood1" />

</layer-list>
```

Even if I replace the image in `launch_background.xml` with just a white color, it still fades to black before rendering the Flutter app.

Any ideas what could be causing the launch screen to fade to black before rendering the app?

Comment: It will go when you release the app. Try to run your app in profile mode with a real device. Then see if that make any difference.

Comment: I'm also having this issue, any news

Comment: It seemed to go away on Android in release mode, but it's there on iOS in both debug/release.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you forgot to add this on your `AndroidManifest`, between **< activity> ... < /activity>**

```
<meta-data
       android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
   android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
/>
```

Comment: This is now deprecated https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/android/splash-screen#android-12